# To prove $512^3+675^3+720^3$ is Composite

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that $$N=512^3+675^3+720^3$$ is Composite

I Used $$a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)+3abc$$ so

$$N=1907(512^2+675^2+720^2-512.675-675.720-720.512)+3.512.675.720$$

But i cannot proceed further